# Typo3 v10 site configuration with a www-subdomain

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x, typo3-11.x

I created a site configuration in Typo3 10.4.11 for the entry point *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*. When browsing to *example.com* (without www), I get an error message:

> Page Not Found The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No
> site configuration found.

I tried to create a *static route*, which didn´t work. Any other ideas how to redirect to the original page from *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)* as well as *example.com*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running on Apache, I'd suggest to add a redirect to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Put the snippet near to the line with `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have both domains served by TYPO3, then the EXT: host_variants may be an option.

https://github.com/b13/host_variants